# Outdated submodule in CircleCI test

Tags: git, github, circleci

Performing an integration using CircleCI I found a problem with the version of a submodule.

I don't know if it is a problem from CircleCI, maybe it's a issue from my GitHub configuration or a misconfigured submodule configuration file.

I have a repository in which there is a client. This client requires a protocol that is in another repository.
The protocol is a client submodule.
I'm using the branch jrpc_if from protocol repository.

*.gitmodules File content is:*

```
[submodule "protocol"]
    path = protocol
    url = git@github.com:satnet-project/protocol.git
    branch = jrpc_if
```

*It also modifies the config file from .git directory, its content is as follows.*

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:satnet-project/generic-client.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "protocol"]
    url = git@github.com:satnet-project/protocol.git
```

To start the submodule I use the following commands. These are in the configuration file, circle.yml.

```
checkout:
  post:
    - git submodule update --init
    - cd protocol && git checkout jrpc_if
```

The last command is just to check the branch. I get this screen output:

```
cd protocol && git checkout jrpc_if

Previous HEAD position was 00936bc... Problems fixed
Switched to branch 'jrpc_if'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/jrpc_if'.
```

The problem is that at perform the protocol tests submodule files do not match the last GitHub repository.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Thank you.

Comment: I know circle tries to do smart things with caching between builds and one of the things it caches is your .git directory.  Have you tried to do a run without cache to see if this helps the problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried and the problem stills persists. Thanks anyway!